# Cannot get results from my custom table anymore

Tags: php, wordpress

I was able to get results before and add into, I am not sure if my SELECT code broke or my INSERT broke, or if my table is not being created anymore.

I just want my table to get populated with new inserts into the db table, better yet inserts to work. Below is my current code for the two main files i'm using. To test I use a FTP to move over my updated files, refresh, and try the buttons. As I said before they worked perfectly fine, up until I created the uninstall function which drops my table.

SOLVED: Whole issue was I made a typo in my table creation code, probably hit backspace by accident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the $wpdb->insert();

Try this:

```
$query    = $wpdb->prepare( "insert into {$table_name} (name,category,url) values (%s,%s,%s)",'test,'test','test');
$inserted = $wpdb->query( $query );

if( $inserted ){
  echo 'ok';
}else{
  echo 'error';
}
```

instead **$wpdb->insert**

Comment: I dropped this code in as my insert, I get the echo 'error'. Is there anyway for me to see the error message?

At least I know now that it's failing on the insert.

Comment: Ok I found out the real reason why my code failed. I accidently removed a "," somehow in my sql to make the table, added that in and now stuff works. I set this as the correct answer because this insert looks alot nicer and I'd bet it prevents sql injections. If not at least it catches errors. Thank you.